# Devexpress export/save chart to client

Tags: devexpress, export, client

I am currently having trouble trying to figure out how to export my Devexpress XtraCharts to either and image file (of any format) or a pdf. Everything I can find either seems to be not implemented yet, not documented really well or doesn't save to the client side.

If anyone could possibly help me out it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [XtraCharts examples](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2458):

- [How to: Export a Chart to PDF](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2506)
- [How to: Export a Chart to Image](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2508)

Or contact the [DevExpress Support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) directly.